# getting values json values from the url using

Tags: javascript, json

I have looked at various posts and now using a function to retrieve values from url but cannot get rid of the %20 characters. The data thats sent is json, here is the code that sends it in url:

```
'<a href="' + url +"?id="+ json_data[i].product_id + 
...
"&description="+ json_data[i].description + '"> //includes white spaces
```

on the other page i have :

```
function getUrlVars()
{
 var vars = [], hash;
 var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
 for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
 {
    hash = hashes[i].split('=');
    vars.push(hash[0]);
    vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
 }
return vars;
}

var selectedData=getUrlVars();
document.write(selectedData.description);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `encodeURIComponent` and `decodeURIComponent` functions:

```
"&description="+ encodeURIComponent(json_data[i].description) + '"
```

And:

```
decoreURIComponent(hash[1]);
```

This will take care of space, but also make things work if there is an `&` sign in the description.
For example:

```
> hash
["clean", "Machine%20washable%2030%20degrees%20reduced%20spin"]
> decodeURIComponent(hash[1]);
"Machine washable 30 degrees reduced spin"
```

Comment: It still adds unwanted characters. I have included `decodeURIComponent(hash[1]);vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];`

Comment: Can you post the value of the ajax url and `window.location.href`? What unwanted characters do you have?

Comment: if you click on an image you will see what i mean

Comment: You need to assign the decoded value to the variable, the original string doesn't change: `vars[hash[0]] = decodeURIComponent(hash[1]);`

Comment: I also did not encode all the values in the string as i was testing just one of them, works fine now.